# Solr: Indexed and stored field returning cannot be queried

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, localsolr

Solr:4.8.1,I have a field called age which stores a single character like A or C and is stored is the field

```
<field name="age" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

When I get results back from other searches I can see the field age and its value but when I search for example `age:*` it returns 0 results. This just happened recently as I have been working with this field for a month and it worked fine but now nothing returns. I altered the schema a few times but nothing regarding this field. The only thing I can think of is that I accidentally put an invalid value into the age field of the mysql database that I import from, but fixed that and re-imported it.

I have searched this problem and found that `<defaultSearchField>` needs to be set but those results were older and that field is now depreciated.

EDIT:

My data config is:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/gtw" 
              user="root" 
              password=""/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id" query="select id,price,title,description,main_image,retailer,link,age,gender,type,category,creation_date from solr_listings">
      <field column="category" name="category" splitBy=","></field>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The only thing that is different from the default example schema are the fields I added below:

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="retailer" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="main_image" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="link" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="gender" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="age" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="type" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="creation_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: To answer your question there may need to be more information about your schema provided.  However, I will take a stab in the dark and ask: are your ages actually stored as text in the database?  Or are they stored as integers?  Maybe the type in your field declaration is wrong.

Comment: The mysql databases gender and age are the same type, char, and in the schema the fields are identical. I can query gender but not age.

Comment: hmm.  I'm not seeing anything obvious.  I will be able to check my own Solr stuff in an hour or so and will compare the two to see if anything jumps out.  Hopefully, someone beats me to an answer, though, so you can move on.  Just for sanity sake, can you do a regular mysql query and retrieve the age column?  Basically, run the same select query from the config file to make sure you get sane results.

Comment: Yeah I the mysql is fine. I removed and recreated the column and still nothing.

Comment: I solved the problem but I'm not sure why it works. I changed from text_general to string and now it I can query the age field.

Comment: Sweet.  I was just comparing your and my documents and couldn't see anything obvious that would explain your outcome.  I'm glad you got it fixed and I wish I could explain why your change mattered.  Maybe someone will happen upon this question and educate us both.

Comment: does `age:[* TO *]` return 0 results too? other that that, can you please show us how `text_general` is defined?

Comment: The reason why text_general didn't work is because short terms (such as a) would be removed as stop words / not relevant for the search result - depending on if you've used the example definition text_general or not. String leaves the value unchanged.

Comment: that should depend entirely on how his analyzer chain is built

Comment: @fiskfisk I'm pretty new to solr and I'm learning as I go. I suspect the stopwords is what fouled it up because I just recently added some definitions. I definitely used the example of text general.

Comment: @omnu_negro age is a character not a number so I don't think a range search would work, unless I'm missing something. Text general is straight out of the example.

Comment: Try using the analysis page from the admin ui, it should tell you how it is being analyzed.